# How can I create a Git branch and merge it back to master with a different tag?

Tags: git, github

I have a repo in github
one branch called master.
it has 3 tags:

```
1.0.0
2.0.0
3.0.0
```

I'd like to take the code from master:2.0.0, modify it and push it back so the end result I'll have one master branch with tags:

```
1.0.0
2.0.0
2.0.1 --> new code
3.0.0
```

so from my machine i do:

```
git clone <repo url>
git checkout tags/2.0.0
git checkout -b feature/fix
(now i modify the code)
git add .
git commit -m "Changed code"
```

I'm really not sure what to do from here. What am I missing?

Comment: Merge back into master and tag it, then push. I'm not clear on the problem. Of course, since you're immediately merging back into master there's not much point to the side branch. The history outcome is the same either way.

Comment: im not being able to merge, if ill edit the code and the type: git merge master, ill get conflicts, 3.0.0 is advanced and there are lots of changes from 2.0.0. so i just want to merge back to 2.0.0 with one small change and call it 2.0.1

Comment: What does "push it back" even mean? Please show diagrams of the actual chain of commits existing and desire, not just a list of some numbers.

Comment: I wish to work on the code on master which correspond to tag 2.0.0 and merge it back to master with tag 2.0.1. 
if i clone the code, work on 2.0.0 and creating 2.0.1 when i merge it back to master git is looking at the diffs between my 2.0.1 and the latest code on master (3.0.0) and there are tons of changes. can i tell git upon merge to compare it to the code on 2.0.0 and not look at the latest code on master?

Comment: Well you have to resolve the conflicts. That's not a showstopper.

Comment: "can i tell git upon merge to compare it to the code on 2.0.0 and not look at the latest code on master?" No, not if the place where you want to put the new commit _is_ after the latest code on master. Perhaps what you really want to do is edit, add, commit, tag as 2.0.1, and _stop_. Why merge anything to anything?

Comment: But if the goal is to _splice_ 2.0.1 into the chain, after 2.0.0 but before 3.0.0, then you would have to _rebase_ all of master after 2.0.0 _onto_ 2.0.1. Easy to do (though conflicts are still possible). But be warned:  now you're changing public history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it the goal is to splice 2.0.1 into the direct chain of master's first-parents. After

```
git clone <repo url>
git checkout tags/2.0.0
git checkout -b feature/fix
(now i modify the code)
git add .
git commit -m "Changed code"
```

You would tag this commit as `2.0.1`.

```
git tag -a 2.0.1
```

Then after tagging you would say

```
git rebase --onto 2.0.1 2.0.0 master
```

Comment: Personally I would have omitted `git checkout -b feature/fix` but it does no harm.

Comment: Note that you have now changed history, so if you push you will need to push with force.